# groupBy Dataset per number of keys with a limit

Tags: scala, apache-spark-dataset

Aggregating dataset based on certain keys , but limiting the aggregated list by fixed number.

Attached the code to create the dataset. Need help to implement mechanism similar to the way grouped() works with list.

```
  case class AggrBook(
                city: String,
                state:String,
                books:List[Int]
              )

  case class Bookings(bookingId: Int,
                  userId:String,
                  city: String,
                  state:String
                 )


val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local")getOrCreate()

import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
val bookDS = spark.createDataset (
  Seq(
    Bookings(1, "ames", "Eureka", "CA"),
    Bookings(2, "cha", "Eureka", "CA"),
    Bookings(3, "ygy", "Eureka", "CA"),
    Bookings(4, "6fsj", "Kettlemen", "AK"),
    Bookings(5, "skj", "Eureka", "CA"),
    Bookings(6, "po", "Irvine", "CA")
  )
)
bookDS.show


val dsGrouped: Dataset[AggrBook] = bookDS.groupByKey(r => (r.city, r.state))
  .mapGroups((key, value) => AggrBook(key._2, key._1, value.map(_.bookingId).toList))
dsGrouped.show()
```

grouped by max 2 for bookingIDs, aggregate the dataset by state,city per record.

My result

```
+----+---------+------------+
|city|    state|       books|
+----+---------+------------+
|  CA|   Eureka|[1, 2, 3, 5]|
|  AK|Kettlemen|         [4]|
|  CA|   Irvine|         [6]|
+----+---------+------------+
```

Expecting :

```
+----+---------+------------+
|city|    state|       books|
+----+---------+------------+
|  CA|   Eureka|[1, 2]      |
|  CA|   Eureka|[3, 5]      |
|  AK|Kettlemen|[4]         |
|  CA|   Irvine|[6]         |
+----+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Could you update your question to include the definitions of `myDataSet`? Including it's type definition. e.g `DataFrame` or `Dataset[Something]`.

Comment: updated. thank you.

Comment: Can you include the line: `val myDataSet: <type-here> = ...`

Comment: updated the question with sample data

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an easy way to achieve what you want using only native Spark functions, but it is can be done using a User Defined Function (UDF) as below:

```
val groupBy2 = udf((s: Seq[Int]) => s.grouped(2).toList)
ss.udf.register("groupBy2", groupBy2)
val dsGrouped: Dataset[AggrBook] = bookDS.groupBy("city", "state").agg(collect_list("bookingId") as "books")
  .withColumn("books", explode(groupBy2(col("books"))))
  .as[AggrBook]
```

The UDF takes a `Seq[Int]` and returns a `Seq[Seq[Int]]` where the inner sequence has a length of two or less. This is then 'expanded' using the native Spark `explode` function to give you (potentially) multiple rows for each 'city-state' pair, but only two IDs in the 'books' column.